# Linux kernel device driver to DMA from a device into user-space memory

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, dma

I want to get data from a DMA enabled, PCIe hardware device into user-space as quickly as possible.

Q: How do I combine "direct I/O to user-space with/and/via a DMA transfer"

1. Reading through LDD3, it seems that I need to perform a few different types of IO operations!?

   `dma_alloc_coherent` gives me the physical address that I can pass to the hardware device.
   But would need to have setup `get_user_pages` and perform a `copy_to_user` type call when the transfer completes. This seems a waste, asking the Device to DMA into kernel memory (acting as buffer) then transferring it again to user-space.
   LDD3 p453: `/* Only now is it safe to access the buffer, copy to user, etc. */`
2. What I ideally want is some memory that:

   - I can use in user-space (Maybe request driver via a ioctl call to create DMA'able memory/buffer?)
   - I can get a physical address from to pass to the device so that all user-space has to do is perform a read on the driver
   - the read method would activate the DMA transfer, block waiting for the DMA complete interrupt and release the user-space read afterwards (user-space is now safe to use/read memory).

Do I need single-page streaming mappings, setup mapping and user-space buffers mapped with `get_user_pages` `dma_map_page`?

My code so far sets up `get_user_pages` at the given address from user-space (I call this the Direct I/O part). Then, `dma_map_page` with a page from `get_user_pages`. I give the device the return value from `dma_map_page` as the DMA physical transfer address.

I am using some kernel modules as reference: `drivers_scsi_st.c` and `drivers-net-sh_eth.c`. I would look at infiniband code, but cant find which one is the most basic!

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: It has been ages since my last driver development under Linux but I always reserved DMA usable memory that was then mapped onto user pages. In the past not all adresses could be used for DMA transfers. This might not be the case nowadays. Another hint might be to have a look at the video for linux drivers especially the ones involving the BT848/BT878 chips. I hope you can find something useful there.

Comment: I know this question is similar : http://stackoverflow.com/q/3333959/119790

Comment: I'm working on a similar problem. I'd be curious to know what route you ended up taking.

Comment: if we use contigious memory (not SG) with dma_alloc_coherent() - which returns contiguous memory - then can't we just call mmap in userspace ?

Comment: @ransh: yes, if your driver implements the mmap file operation.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I'm actually working on exactly the same thing right now and I'm going the `ioctl()` route. The general idea is for user space to allocate the buffer which will be used for the DMA transfer and an `ioctl()` will be used to pass the size and address of this buffer to the device driver. The driver will then use scatter-gather lists along with the streaming DMA API to transfer data directly to and from the device and user-space buffer.

The implementation strategy I'm using is that the `ioctl()` in the driver enters a loop that DMA's the userspace buffer in chunks of 256k (which is the hardware imposed limit for how many scatter/gather entries it can handle). This is isolated inside a function that blocks until each transfer is complete (see below). When all bytes are transfered or the incremental transfer function returns an error the `ioctl()` exits and returns to userspace

Pseudo code for the `ioctl()`

```cpp
/*serialize all DMA transfers to/from the device*/
if (mutex_lock_interruptible( &device_ptr->mtx ) )
    return -EINTR;

chunk_data = (unsigned long) user_space_addr;
while( *transferred < total_bytes && !ret ) {
    chunk_bytes = total_bytes - *transferred;
    if (chunk_bytes > HW_DMA_MAX)
        chunk_bytes = HW_DMA_MAX; /* 256kb limit imposed by my device */
    ret = transfer_chunk(device_ptr, chunk_data, chunk_bytes, transferred);
    chunk_data += chunk_bytes;
    chunk_offset += chunk_bytes;
}

mutex_unlock(&device_ptr->mtx);
```

Pseudo code for incremental transfer function:

```cpp
/*Assuming the userspace pointer is passed as an unsigned long, */
/*calculate the first,last, and number of pages being transferred via*/

first_page = (udata & PAGE_MASK) >> PAGE_SHIFT;
last_page = ((udata+nbytes-1) & PAGE_MASK) >> PAGE_SHIFT;
first_page_offset = udata & PAGE_MASK;
npages = last_page - first_page + 1;

/* Ensure that all userspace pages are locked in memory for the */
/* duration of the DMA transfer */

down_read(&current->mm->mmap_sem);
ret = get_user_pages(current,
                     current->mm,
                     udata,
                     npages,
                     is_writing_to_userspace,
                     0,
                     &pages_array,
                     NULL);
up_read(&current->mm->mmap_sem);

/* Map a scatter-gather list to point at the userspace pages */

/*first*/
sg_set_page(&sglist[0], pages_array[0], PAGE_SIZE - fp_offset, fp_offset);

/*middle*/
for(i=1; i < npages-1; i++)
    sg_set_page(&sglist[i], pages_array[i], PAGE_SIZE, 0);

/*last*/
if (npages > 1) {
    sg_set_page(&sglist[npages-1], pages_array[npages-1],
        nbytes - (PAGE_SIZE - fp_offset) - ((npages-2)*PAGE_SIZE), 0);
}

/* Do the hardware specific thing to give it the scatter-gather list
   and tell it to start the DMA transfer */

/* Wait for the DMA transfer to complete */
ret = wait_event_interruptible_timeout( &device_ptr->dma_wait, 
         &device_ptr->flag_dma_done, HZ*2 );

if (ret == 0)
    /* DMA operation timed out */
else if (ret == -ERESTARTSYS )
    /* DMA operation interrupted by signal */
else {
    /* DMA success */
    *transferred += nbytes;
    return 0;
}
```

The interrupt handler is exceptionally brief:

```cpp
/* Do hardware specific thing to make the device happy */

/* Wake the thread waiting for this DMA operation to complete */
device_ptr->flag_dma_done = 1;
wake_up_interruptible(device_ptr->dma_wait);
```

Please note that this is just a general approach, I've been working on this driver for the last few weeks and have yet to actually test it... So please, don't treat this pseudo code as gospel and be sure to double check all logic and parameters ;-).

Comment: Although the solution didnt directly help me, it was an interesting read. As the only answer, I'll accept this by default. But much respect and credit is due for a well written answer.

Comment: I know this thread was started 5 years ago but here's hoping that my question will not be ignored.  It seems that, with the exception of user405725's answer, one must wait for the DMA to complete.  Without doing so would mean that, perhaps, user pages are unnecessarily left pinned if something goes wrong.  Am I correct?  This seems to be a very much synchronous operation.  Correct?

Comment: Correct. It would be possible to do the DMA asynchronously, I suppose, but some kind of notification would need to be provided to the userspace application so they would know when the memory may be safely used/overwritten. Synchronous was easy to implement though so that was the path I chose. As for things going wrong, you're kind of screwed if they do and i'm not sure it's even detectable. I haven't looked at this in 5 years though so I'm definitely out of date ;-)

Comment: for future readers: note that ioctls are usually significantly less performant than dma (but it's usually fine for most use-cases).

Comment: You also need to create a streaming DMA mapping for the sg to talk to the (specific) device. `dma_map_sg()`. That's the whole point of building the scatterlist.

Comment: I managed to use this answer to make a DMA kernel module. It's not exactly same as what the question asked for, but maybe the source code will help people out:
https://github.com/esophagus-now/mpsoc_axidma

Answer (score 15):

You basically have the right idea: in 2.1, you can just have userspace allocate any old memory.  You do want it page-aligned, so `posix_memalign()` is a handy API to use.

Then have userspace pass in the userspace virtual address and size of this buffer somehow; ioctl() is a good quick and dirty way to do this.  In the kernel, allocate an appropriately sized buffer array of `struct page*` -- `user_buf_size/PAGE_SIZE` entries -- and use `get_user_pages()` to get a list of struct page* for the userspace buffer.

Once you have that, you can allocate an array of `struct scatterlist` that is the same size as your page array and loop through the list of pages doing `sg_set_page()`.  After the sg list is set up, you do `dma_map_sg()` on the array of scatterlist and then you can get the `sg_dma_address` and `sg_dma_len` for each entry in the scatterlist (note you have to use the return value of `dma_map_sg()` because you may end up with fewer mapped entries because things might get merged by the DMA mapping code).

That gives you all the bus addresses to pass to your device, and then you can trigger the DMA and wait for it however you want.  The read()-based scheme you have is probably fine.

You can refer to drivers/infiniband/core/umem.c, specifically `ib_umem_get()`, for some code that builds up this mapping, although the generality that that code needs to deal with may make it a bit confusing.

Alternatively, if your device doesn't handle scatter/gather lists too well and you want contiguous memory, you could use `get_free_pages()` to allocate a physically contiguous buffer and use `dma_map_page()` on that.  To give userspace access to that memory, your driver just needs to implement an `mmap` method instead of the ioctl as described above.

Comment: if we use contigious memory (not SG) with dma_alloc_coherent() - which returns contiguous memory - then can't we just call mmap in userspace ?

Answer (score 7):

At some point I wanted to allow user-space application to allocate DMA buffers and get it mapped to user-space and get the physical address to be able to control my device and do DMA transactions (bus mastering) entirely from user-space, totally bypassing the Linux kernel. I have used a little bit different approach though. First I started with a minimal kernel module that was initializing/probing PCIe device and creating a character device. That driver then allowed a user-space application to do two things:

1. Map PCIe device's I/O bar into user-space using `remap_pfn_range()` function.
2. Allocate and free DMA buffers, map them to user space and pass a physical bus address to user-space application.

Basically, it boils down to a custom implementation of `mmap()` call (though `file_operations`). One for I/O bar is easy:

```
struct vm_operations_struct a2gx_bar_vma_ops = {
};

static int a2gx_cdev_mmap_bar2(struct file *filp, struct vm_area_struct *vma)
{
    struct a2gx_dev *dev;
    size_t size;

    size = vma->vm_end - vma->vm_start;
    if (size != 134217728)
        return -EIO;

    dev = filp->private_data;
    vma->vm_ops = &a2gx_bar_vma_ops;
    vma->vm_page_prot = pgprot_noncached(vma->vm_page_prot);
    vma->vm_private_data = dev;

    if (remap_pfn_range(vma, vma->vm_start,
                        vmalloc_to_pfn(dev->bar2),
                        size, vma->vm_page_prot))
    {
        return -EAGAIN;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

And another one that allocates DMA buffers using `pci_alloc_consistent()` is a little bit more complicated:

```
static void a2gx_dma_vma_close(struct vm_area_struct *vma)
{
    struct a2gx_dma_buf *buf;
    struct a2gx_dev *dev;

    buf = vma->vm_private_data;
    dev = buf->priv_data;

    pci_free_consistent(dev->pci_dev, buf->size, buf->cpu_addr, buf->dma_addr);
    buf->cpu_addr = NULL; /* Mark this buffer data structure as unused/free */
}

struct vm_operations_struct a2gx_dma_vma_ops = {
    .close = a2gx_dma_vma_close
};

static int a2gx_cdev_mmap_dma(struct file *filp, struct vm_area_struct *vma)
{
    struct a2gx_dev *dev;
    struct a2gx_dma_buf *buf;
    size_t size;
    unsigned int i;

    /* Obtain a pointer to our device structure and calculate the size
       of the requested DMA buffer */
    dev = filp->private_data;
    size = vma->vm_end - vma->vm_start;

    if (size < sizeof(unsigned long))
        return -EINVAL; /* Something fishy is happening */

    /* Find a structure where we can store extra information about this
       buffer to be able to release it later. */
    for (i = 0; i < A2GX_DMA_BUF_MAX; ++i) {
        buf = &dev->dma_buf[i];
        if (buf->cpu_addr == NULL)
            break;
    }

    if (buf->cpu_addr != NULL)
        return -ENOBUFS; /* Oops, hit the limit of allowed number of
                            allocated buffers. Change A2GX_DMA_BUF_MAX and
                            recompile? */

    /* Allocate consistent memory that can be used for DMA transactions */
    buf->cpu_addr = pci_alloc_consistent(dev->pci_dev, size, &buf->dma_addr);
    if (buf->cpu_addr == NULL)
        return -ENOMEM; /* Out of juice */

    /* There is no way to pass extra information to the user. And I am too lazy
       to implement this mmap() call using ioctl(). So we simply tell the user
       the bus address of this buffer by copying it to the allocated buffer
       itself. Hacks, hacks everywhere. */
    memcpy(buf->cpu_addr, &buf->dma_addr, sizeof(buf->dma_addr));

    buf->size = size;
    buf->priv_data = dev;
    vma->vm_ops = &a2gx_dma_vma_ops;
    vma->vm_page_prot = pgprot_noncached(vma->vm_page_prot);
    vma->vm_private_data = buf;

    /*
     * Map this DMA buffer into user space.
     */
    if (remap_pfn_range(vma, vma->vm_start,
                        vmalloc_to_pfn(buf->cpu_addr),
                        size, vma->vm_page_prot))
    {
        /* Out of luck, rollback... */
        pci_free_consistent(dev->pci_dev, buf->size, buf->cpu_addr,
                            buf->dma_addr);
        buf->cpu_addr = NULL;
        return -EAGAIN;
    }

    return 0; /* All good! */
}
```

Once those are in place, user space application can pretty much do everything — control the device by reading/writing from/to I/O registers, allocate and free DMA buffers of arbitrary size, and have the device perform DMA transactions. The only missing part is interrupt-handling. I was doing polling in user space, burning my CPU, and had interrupts disabled.

Hope it helps. Good Luck!

Comment: Your [link](http://lazarenko.me/2013/05/12/kernel-bypass-technique/) appears to be a 404?

Answer (score 2):

> I'm getting confused with the direction to implement. I want to...

Consider the application when designing a driver.
What is the nature of data movement, frequency, size and what else might be going on in the system?

Is the traditional read/write API sufficient?
Is direct mapping the device into user space OK?
Is a reflective (semi-coherent) shared memory desirable?

Manually manipulating data (read/write) is a pretty good option if the data lends itself to being well understood.  Using general purpose VM and read/write may be sufficient with an inline copy.  Direct mapping non cachable accesses to the peripheral is convenient, but can be clumsy.  If the access is the relatively infrequent movement of large blocks, it may make sense to use regular memory, have the drive pin, translate addresses, DMA and release the pages.  As an optimization, the pages (maybe huge) can be pre pinned and translated; the drive then can recognize the prepared memory and avoid the complexities of dynamic translation.  If there are lots of little I/O operations, having the drive run asynchronously makes sense.  If elegance is important, the VM dirty page flag can be used to automatically identify what needs to be moved and a (meta_sync()) call can be used to flush pages.  Perhaps a mixture of the above works...

Too often people don't look at the larger problem, before digging into the details. Often the simplest solutions are sufficient. A little effort constructing a behavioral model can help guide what API is preferable.

Answer (score 0):

```
first_page_offset = udata & PAGE_MASK;
```

It seems wrong. It should be either:

```
first_page_offset = udata & ~PAGE_MASK;
```

or

```
first_page_offset = udata & (PAGE_SIZE - 1)
```

Comment: This is correct.  In the linux kernel, `PAGE_MASK` is almost universally defined to be `(~(PAGE_SIZE-1))`, so `udata & PAGE_MASK` would mask out the page offset instead of retaining it.

Answer (score 0):

It is worth mention that driver with Scatter-Gather DMA support and user space memory allocation is most efficient and has highest performance. However in case we don't need high performance or we want to develop a driver in some simplified conditions we can use some tricks.

Give up zero copy design. It is worth to consider when data throughput is not too big. In such a design data can by copied to user by
`copy_to_user(user_buffer, kernel_dma_buffer, count);`
user_buffer might be for example buffer argument in character device read() system call implementation. We still need to take care of `kernel_dma_buffer` allocation. It might by memory obtained from `dma_alloc_coherent()` call for example.

The another trick is to limit system memory at the boot time and then use it as huge contiguous DMA buffer. It is especially useful during driver and FPGA DMA controller development and rather not recommended in production environments. Lets say PC has 32GB of RAM. If we add `mem=20GB` to kernel boot parameters list we can use 12GB as huge contiguous dma buffer. To map this memory to user space simply implement mmap() as

```
remap_pfn_range(vma,
    vma->vm_start,
    (0x500000000 >> PAGE_SHIFT) + vma->vm_pgoff, 
    vma->vm_end - vma->vm_start,
    vma->vm_page_prot)
```

Of course this 12GB is completely omitted by OS and can be used only by process which has mapped it into its address space. We can try to avoid it by using Contiguous Memory Allocator (CMA).

Again above tricks will not replace full Scatter-Gather, zero copy DMA driver, but are useful during development time or in some less performance platforms.

Comment: Why giving up zero copy design? What's the issue with mapping DMA memory into user space and use it from the user space?

Comment: The only difference between SGDMA and what you say is the contiguous physical memory, not the size of the whole memory allocated. In the end the userspace will see the same amount of contiguous virtual memory and the device will see chunks of PAGE_SIZE memory addresses. Am I wrong?